# how to receive string from server after ajax call

Tags: jquery, asp.net, ajax

i am new to ajax and i found it very easy to send data from client to the server, the opposite have been difficult to achieve.

all i want is to send some params to my asp server and receive a string in return when callback is done.
this is my call for ajax:

```
$.ajax(
         { url: "Default.aspx"}, 
         { ajaxPost:"post", 
           ajaxPostValName: name, 
           ajaxPostValDate: currdate, 
           ajaxPostValFile: file, 
           ajaxPostValCell: cell, 
           ajaxPostValChannel: channel}).done(
               function ( "need string result from here") { "do my string parsing here" });
```

i tried getting the data using "data" var in the done func but i get the whole page.

suggestions?

thanks

Comment: look at the syntax of .done function

Comment: mark a page method (not whole page) as a webmethod and call it, sending back what you want.  Example "default.aspx/mymethod"

Comment: hi mark,  i added the [WebMethod] attribute on a public method as you recommended but now the ajax call don't seems to summon that method, or even the Page_Load.  maybe i am doing something wrong?

Answer (score 0):

You only have to echo something in your `Default.aspx` and call your ajax this way

```
$.ajax({ url: "Default.aspx"}, { ajaxPost:"post", ajaxPostValName: name, ajaxPostValDate: currdate, ajaxPostValFile: file, ajaxPostValCell: cell, ajaxPostValChannel: channel}).done(
function ( data ) { 
    //do what you want with the data variable
});
```

Comment: thanks Philippe, but if i echo the string it only add it to the data so i get in return my string appended with the whole page.  i need only the string as a result (i may want to parse it later as json).

Comment: I'm not sure to understand, your data variable contains the whole page plus the string you want ?

Comment: yes. before doing the echo on the server the data var was filled with the page itself, and after doing the echo  the var is filled with the wanted string + the page content.  it seems that the echo concate the strings to the returned data result which is already filled with the page content

Comment: The data variable will always contains everithing default.aspx will output, you need to call a page that only output what you need

Comment: thanks for the quick replay! ok so i need to override some kind of default output? because i did not handled any page output so i dont have any idea why the request is returning the page content as output.

Comment: I don't know if you use a .NET framework or CMS, but you could call another .aspx page with only what you need. Try creating mypage.aspx with this example json output : `{"firstName": "John","lastName":"Smith"}`